# How to remove selected elements from a QGIS legend?

Tags: qgis, legend, qgis-2.8, formatting

I'm working with a QGIS project with a number of layers. When assembling a printout all visible layers are automatically added to the legend:

[image: 1st legend]

I would like to exercise some control over the legend elements are remove some of the entries:

[image: 2nd legend]

However, as the entries correspond to the upper levels in the hierarchy, deleting them will remove the keys:

> 1 - 20000
>    20000 - 40000
>    ...

---

I'm working in Qgis 2.8. I'm not interested in modifying my layer structure but only in changing the legend elements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of deleting legend items, you could **hide** them. From the *Legend items* options window, right-click the name of the layer and select the *Hidden* option:

[image: Hide layer names]

This would hide the names of layers, leaving the values:

[image: Result]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves my problem. Can I also ask if there is a convenient way of removing decimal places that are visible in your legend? I use QGIS to classify some of the variables automatically and on a few occasions I had to edit the legend by hand. I would like to automatically determine the number of decimal places generated and visible in the legend.

Comment: @Konrad - Most welcome buddy! For the layers I used, they were made using the **Graduated** style. There's a _Precision_ option which you can edit to increase/decrease the amount of decimal places. The legend should be automatically updated with the new precision...hopefully :)

Comment: this is excellent. Thank you very much for the useful advice.

Comment: @Konrad - My pleasure, hope you get the legend the way you want it to look :)

Comment: I have found that the layers I don't want to show on the legend are already marked "Hidden". However there is a 'minus sign button' below the list of layers which does the trick